# Can you hang a heavy punching bag where a ceiling fan mount is?

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan, mount

My apartment is newly refurbished with multiple pre-installed spots for lighting fixtures, including ceiling fans.

It would seem to me that a metal beam that can handle a ceiling fan can handle a punching bag. Am I missing something and, if not, any tips on how to pull it off?

Comment: A ceiling fan is a *mostly* static weight of around 20 lbs. It exerts virtually no lateral force on its mount. You'd have to tell us more about this "metal beam", as well as what "heavy" means. Photos would help.

Answer (score 6):

Ceiling fan boxes only have to support 35 lbs. ceiling fans (according to NEC), unless they are designed to support more. In which case they will be marked with the amount they can support, up to the maximum of 70 lbs.

So no, I would not recommend hanging a punching bag (assuming a [heavy bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punching_bag#Types_of_bag)) from a ceiling fan bracket.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that "metal beam" means the fan bracket. It could also mean a structural ceiling member, as in the bottom chord of a truss.

Comment: @isherwood Sure, "*metal beam*" could mean a lot of things.  I'm just pointing out that just because you can hang a ceiling fan from it, doesn't mean it's strong enough for a punching bag.

Comment: We're singing the same tune.